# How do I insert a Django template variable into a React script?

Tags: django, reactjs

I am using Django Rest Framework with React.js. My page shows one user's profile, using an api like this:

`http://localhost:8000/api/profile/[pk]`

I want to dynamically set the url for the react ajax request to include the proper pk, so that it requests the correct user's information from the server.

I could use a function like window.location.href and pop the number from the end, but is there a way to do this by passing the pk directly from the server, i.e., using a template variable?

Comment: Or your react.js code could request the id during its login process, get it via JSON and store it during the duration of the request? I generally feel if you're interacting with JSON and implementing an API, it should be just that, an API, not a templated thing.

Comment: @jvc26 right now my react code doesn't use a router, it's just one feature showing details for a particular profile. The rest of the page is django templating. My current solution is to add an html5 data tag to the element holding the react code and put the url there. Not very pretty but working for now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you render the component, you should pass the pk as a prop.

```
<script>
React.render(React.createElement(Profile, {
    userId: "{{ userId }}", 
    urlPrefix: "/api/profile/" 
}), element);
</script>
```

A better alternative might be to just fetch the user, and then render the component.  For example, with superagent:

```
superagent.get('/api/profile/{{ userId }}', function(res){
    React.render(React.createElement(Profile, 
        {user: res.body}
    ), element);
});
```

---

With browserify, you can either include data in a script tag, and use that in your code:

```
<script>var _appData = {userId: "{{ userId }}"};</script>
```

Or export modules using the `-r` flag (`.require()` in the api).

```
# sh
browserify -r react -r src/profile.js:profile.js

// js
b.require('react').require('src/profile.js', {expose: 'profile.js'});
```

And then use the modules in regular script tags

```
<script>
var React = require('react');
var Profile = require('profile.js');

React.render(React.createElement(Profile, {
    userId: "{{ userId }}", 
    urlPrefix: "/api/profile/" 
}), element);
</script>
```

Comment: Hm - right now I use a file called "app.js" that's built with browserify. I just call this from my django template like `<script src="app.js"></script>` so I don't think this solution works. Is there another workaround?

Comment: I added some examples for usage with browserify (and updated it to be 0.12/0.13 compatible).

Comment: I assume the <script> tag is part of your html page. But how do you translate the code to javascript? Can browserify handle html?

Comment: The question was asking about django which has server side templates using that syntax. It could be handlebars, or your template language of choice.

Comment: I am really confused about the <script> tag. The browser complains "require is not defined". Can you give a complete example about how to define profile.js, how to use browserify to compile it, and how to include the compiled js file into html file?

Comment: @TaoHuang there are many articles about using browserify with react, I suggest reading one or two of them.