# Conflict with ReactJS curly-braces

Tags: python, django, reactjs, curly-braces

I want to make a aplication with reactJS and django(python) but i have a conflict with the double curly braces of django, before change to reactjs i  began to use angularJS and and could change the double curly braces for {$, is there something similar in reactjs.
I needfor example this in reactjs: `var django = {{ somedjangovalue }}`

I have try to make this `<p>"{% templatetag openvariable %} some text {% templatetag closevariable %}"</p>`

but give me this

> "{{some text}}"

and cant use it.

and `<p>{% templatetag openvariable %} campo {% templatetag closevariable %}</p>`

Give me this problem:

> Error: Parse Error: Line 72: Unexpected token {
>       at http://127.0.0.1:8000/react/ var aux = {{ campo }}

Comment: Implement it correctly by fetching the values from the DOM, thus alleviating the need for a new template tag and also making the separation clearer. Or 1-up, implement endpoints for your React app to fetch data from.

Comment: Ok looks like a found a solution here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478394/how-do-i-insert-a-django-template-variable-into-a-react-script