# Django back end with a React front end

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, react-router

## The idea

I've started off building this social media kind of website, which includes the basic social media pages such as a profile, a status feed, searching, events, and so on. Each page is a seperate django template and data is visualized by using variables in the django template engine. But at this point, I want to change these static pages to something more dynamic, using **ReactJS**.

### But how?

I would like to make the pages dynamic, but it should still be a **multi page** website with urls like `/user/<id>`. I came up with the following option:

**A template for each page. Each page having one bundle. Let Django handle the routes.**

- Create a seperate Django template for each page, just like a normal Django application would do.
- Use [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) to load bundles.
- Each page has a seperate bundle. Bundles are created by adding multiple entries in `webpack.config.js`. This can result in a fairly large amount of entry points when we have 40+ different pages.
- URLs are handled by Django and are accessible by React via a public **javascript** variable in the template. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26484617/2315022). And other initial data for the page (such as username, avatar, profile information) are also loaded in this variable via the Django template engine.
- Dynamic features such as form validations without reloading the page are handled by **React** and a **Django Rest API** using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

### So?

- Is this the correct way to deal with this?
- I am having some trouble figuring out how to get a django template variable such as `request.user` to a javascript variable accessible by React.
- If so, how should I structure such application?
- Is it alright to have a bundle for each separate page? All pages have the same header for example. Including this header in each bundle seems overkill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your plan should work, but I think you should consider how much of your application you want to be dynamic.

If you only need a few pages to have the dynamic functionality that comes from React, it's probably a good idea to just plop in some self-contained React components and bundle them separately as you have planned. However, if most of your project will need to be dynamic, I think it would be best to forget about Django templates for most of the pages, and just create a solid API backend for React to use.

Here is a quick example of how you can configure webpack to bundle up your react components:

This is an excerpt from a large Django project where we are using a couple React components. `bundle` has a bunch of other javascript stuff, and `report` is a self-contained React component:

*webpack.config.js*

```
    ...
    entry: {
        bundle: './server/apps/core/static/core/app.js',
        report: './server/apps/reports/static/reports/js/app.jsx'
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve('./server/apps/core/static/core/bundles'),
      path: path.resolve('./server/apps/core/static/core/bundles'),
      filename: 'bundle.js' + filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    ...
```

And then in the template that you want to stick the component it:

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="root"></div>
{% endblock content %}
{% block extrascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataUrl = "{% url 'reports:data-chart' %}";
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'core/bundles/report.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock extrascripts %}
```

I have another example [here](https://github.com/denvaar/drf-react-boilerplate) that might be helpful to play around with. I need to update it, but it is more of a boilerplate for using React with Django REST Framework, and foregoing the Django template system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Think of a common website layout: header, content, footer. The header has some dynamic components: Search bar with instant search, dropdown menu. The footer is completely static. The content depends on the page. Profile page can have some dynamic components: status feed, popups. Register pages need form validation without reloading the page. 
I keep thinking React is not the best solution, since it is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a viable course.

This has a few good solutions to your question about getting template variables into JS variables for React: [How do I insert a Django template variable into a React script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478394/how-do-i-insert-a-django-template-variable-into-a-react-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You should be able to bundle any combined JS and structure your templates such that each pulls the appropriate bundle.  For instance, I'd expect you to have a base template that includes the header (and any other site-wide HTML), and then extend that template for your individual pages.