# How to pass Django server variable into React jsx?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, webpack

I have a Django view that passes a model queryset and a string variable (`order`)

```
class RestaurantListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Restaurant
    context_object_name = 'restaurants'
    template_name = 'routeyourfood/restodetails.html'
    paginate_by = 4

    @method_decorator(require_GET)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RestaurantListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        self.pids = self.request.session['place_ids']
        self.order = self.kwargs['order']

        self.ordering_dict = {
            'rating-asc': 'rating',
            'rating-desc': '-rating',
            'name-asc': 'name',
            'name-desc': '-name',
            'distance-asc': 'distance_from_route',
            'distance-desc': '-distance_from_route'
        }

        if self.order == 'default':
            return Restaurant.objects.filter(place_id__in=self.pids)
        return Restaurant.objects.filter(place_id__in=self.pids).order_by(self.ordering_dict[self.order])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RestaurantListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['order'] = self.kwargs['order']
        return context
```

I am trying to implement `ReactJS` into my front end.

Currently, my template, `restodetails.html` has only a few `CSS` tags and no `JS` tag.

I construct the entire page using just the template variables I have passed.

But I can't see how I can integrate React into this.

One way I got was to put React into a `<script>` tag in the `head` section, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26484617/4305436).

But I'm keeping my React code in separate JSX files in the Django static folder, which I'm bundling using Webpack.

I also don't like the idea of putting JavaScript into the template.

Is there a way to pass those context variables into the JSX files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know there is no direct way of sending the context variables into the JSX files.

What you could do is create an API that makes the information available and let React do the Ajax call in order to get the information.

You could also decided to only create a variable in the `<script>` part like below.

```
 <script>
 var context_data = <<context data here>>;
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking of creating an API view that responds to AJAX calls from React, but I didn't want to create a whole new view. Thought of integrating the existing `RestaurantListView` with React front-end.
But anyway, I think I'd probably just keep the code as it is. React doesn't seem very useful here, to me.

Comment: I believe you should always try to avoid using an extra library. If React would give you extra options that you are really wanting to use on your website, I recommend using it. If a simple `ListView` can achieve the same result go for that.

Comment: `ListView` was sufficient, but I am learning ReactJS now, and I wanted to use it as much as I could, in as many different ways as I can.